# Lists and Loops in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to find a maximum/minimum value corresponding to a day.

list1 includes all 7 days of the week.
list two is empty []
I have a loop that iterates as many times as the len of list 1,(7), which asks the user to input how many hours they did an activity each day.
how can I print the day that has the max/min value??

```
count = 0
list1 = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

list2 = []
total = 0
for x in range(len(list1)):
    try:
        num = float(input(f"Enter amount of hours of exercise for {list1[x]}: "))
        list2.append(num)
        total += num
    except:
        print("Please enter a number.")
        sys.exit()
    total = sum(list2)

#THESE LINES ARE WHERE I AM HAVING DIFFICULTY!

mamimum = max(list2[list1])
minimum = min(list2[list1])                

print("Day with most amount of exercise: ", maximum)
print("Day with least amount of exercise: ", minimum)
```

Comment: First find the maximum/minimum value then use list's "index" method to find the index into the lists where the value is. ShlomiF's answer shows a more advanced way.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have list1 and list2 (which are not very successfull names), what you want is the index of the maximal/minimal value of list2. This is called argmax/argmin respectively, and can be obtained easily using `np.argmax` (or `np.argmin`).
However, it's also simple using "clean" python, with no unnecessary imports, for instance by using the `key` argument of the built-in `max` (`min`) function:

```
max_index = max(range(7), key=lambda i: list2[i])
min_index = min(range(7), key=lambda i: list2[i])
```

And if you've got the index, then you've got your max/min day and amount:

```
print(f'Maximal amount of exercise was {list2[max_index]}, which was obtained on {list1[max_index]}')
print(f'Minimal amount of exercise was {list2[min_index]}, which was obtained on {list1[min_index]}')
```

---

On an unrelated note, notice than you don't need to loop over `range(len(list1))`, if you're doing that just so you get indexes with which you then use `list1[x]`. You can just directly loop over `list1`.
So your code would be a little better as follows (changing names while I'm at it):

```
count = 0
week_days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

exercise_amounts = []
total = 0
for wd in week_days:
    try:
        num = float(input(f"Enter amount of hours of exercise for {wd}: "))
        exercise_amounts.append(num)
        total += num
    except:
        print("Please enter a number.")
        sys.exit()
    total = sum(exercise_amounts)

max_index = max(range(7), key=lambda i: exercise_amounts[i])
min_index = min(range(7), key=lambda i: exercise_amounts[i])

print(f'Maximal amount of exercise was {exercise_amounts[max_index]}, which was obtained on {week_days[max_index]}')
print(f'Minimal amount of exercise was {exercise_amounts[min_index]}, which was obtained on {week_days[min_index]}')
```

Comment: What if they have more than one max/min value?

Comment: Then the OP needs to specify what they *want* in such a situation.  This isn't about writing production worthy deal-with-edge-cases code, but rather about helping the OP help themeselves. They can take ideas/code/concepts/fixes and generalize and improve for their use-case.

Comment: Why not provide the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a dictonary by `zipping` them out of values print `max` and `min` key value pairs

```
count = 0
import sys
list1 = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

list2 = []
total = 0
for x in range(len(list1)):
    try:
        num = float(input(f"Enter amount of hours of exercise for {list1[x]}: "))
        list2.append(num)
        total += num
    except:
        print("Please enter a number.")
        sys.exit()
    total = sum(list2)

#THESE LINES ARE WHERE I AM HAVING DIFFICULTY!
print(list2)
zipper =dict(zip(list1, list2))         

print("Day with most amount of exercise: ",  [k for k, v in zipper.items() if v == max(zipper.values())])
print("Day with least amount of exercise: ",  [k for k, v in zipper.items() if v == min(zipper.values())])
```

output #

```
Day with most amount of exercise:  ['Sunday', 'Monday']
Day with least amount of exercise:  ['Tuesday']
```

Comment: They only want the day, not the time. Secondly, what if there is more than one day with the same max/min. For example, both Saturday and Sunday have `7 hours`, but your code will return the first one, in this case `Sunday`.

Comment: What is he gone do with day alone?...At last  printing day and time makes sense..He can even print keys know by simply filtering keys. if OP wants he will ask it.

Comment: "how can I print the day that has the max/min value??". I don't see them mentioning `time`. What I am trying to convey is to give them their desired solution.

Comment: Also, what about the second statement?

Comment: ` "how can I print the day that has the max/min value??" ` ...It's the day with max value not alone day.

Comment: It's the `day` that has the `max` value. Also, ignore that point it can simply be removed by indexing. What if they have more than one day with the same max or min value? Let's cater to this.

Answer (score 0):

First you can find the index of maximum and minimum in list 2, then print the values in list 1:

```
count = 0
list1 = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

list2 = []
total = 0
for x in range(len(list1)):
    try:
        num = float(input(f"Enter amount of hours of exercise for {list1[x]}: "))
        list2.append(num)
        total += num
    except:
        print("Please enter a number.")
    total = sum(list2)
    

#THESE LINES ARE WHERE I AM HAVING DIFFICULTY!
max_index = list2.index((max(list2)))
min_index = list2.index((min(list2)))

print("Day with most amount of exercise: ", list1[max_index])
print("Day with least amount of exercise: ", list1[min_index])
```

If you have more than one value for Max or Min:

```
max_days = [list1[i] for i, j in enumerate(list2) if j == max(list2)]
min_days = [list1[i] for i, j in enumerate(list2) if j == min(list2)]

print("Day with most amount of exercise: ", max_days)
print("Day with least amount of exercise: ", min_days)
```

Comment: Same thing, what about more than one value?

Answer (score -1):

Your approach also works pretty well. Here's the fix on your approach:

```
count = 0
list1 = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

list2 = []
total = 0
for x in range(len(list1)):
    try:
        num = float(input(f"Enter amount of hours of exercise for {list1[x]}: "))
        list2.append(num)
        total += num
    except:
        print("Please enter a number.")
        sys.exit()
    total = sum(list2)
maximum = max(list2) # gets the max value corresponding to list2
minimum = min(list2) # gets the min value corresponding to list2
# Compatibility for two max/min values:
def moreThanTwo(value, lst):
    return [i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j == value] # returns the index with max/min values
maximum = [list1[idx] for idx in moreThanTwo(maximum, list2)] # gets the max values
minimum = [list1[idx] for idx in moreThanTwo(minimum, list2)] # gets the min values
print(f"Day with most amount of exercise: {', '.join(maximum)}")
print(f"Day with least amount of exercise: {', '.join(minimum)}")
```

However, I would suggest using a `dictionary` approach like this:

```
days = {"Sunday": 0, "Monday": 0, "Tuesday": 0, "Wednesday": 0, "Thursday": 0, "Friday": 0, "Saturday": 0} # day : time
for key, value in days.items():
    try:
        days[key] = float(input(f"Enter amount of hours of exercise for {key}: ")) # update value in dict
    except:
        print("Please enter a number.")
        exit() # you don't need sys.exit()

maximum = max(days.values()) # gets the max value corresponding to days
minimum = min(days.values()) # gets the min value corresponding to days
# Compatibility for two max/min values:
def moreThanTwo(value, days):
    return [k for k, v in days.items() if v == value] # returns the day with max/min values
maximum =  moreThanTwo(maximum, days) # gets the max values
minimum = moreThanTwo(minimum, days) # gets the min values
print(f"Day with most amount of exercise: {', '.join(maximum)}")
print(f"Day with least amount of exercise: {', '.join(minimum)}")
```